# No access control allow origin in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cors, httprequest

I am getting this error while I am trying to hit on my api deployed on Heroku in rails application using Ruby on rails :

```
 Failed to load https://**: my API link deployed on Heroku No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
 Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: You have not provided much info but check this articles on how to handle ssl on heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#provision-the-add-on && https://readysteadycode.com/howto-setup-ssl-with-rails-and-heroku

Answer (score 2):

http://localhost:3000 is not permitted via CORS. You need to set it up in your rails application deployed on heroku.

Add the below snippet to your `config/application.rb` file and then redeploy to heroku

```
  config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins 'http://localhost:3000'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
    end
  end
```